How is Eladio's relationship with Fring consistent between Better Call Saul and Breaking Bad?
It is clear that Better Call Saul occurs before Breaking Bad.
In the Better Call Saul episode "Point and Shoot," Lalo is filming Fring, and Fring really lays into Eladio on tape for Eladio to hear. Yet later on, in Breaking Bad, Eladio invites Fring to his home.
Is this consistent because Eladio already knew that Fring hates him (for very good reason) but believes he can control Fring? Indeed, probably except for Salamancas, who exhibit family loyalty, no one really likes anyone else and only works together for business reasons and/or out of fear.

Eladio has no idea Lalo's video camera exists, let alone the incriminating evidence of Gus's secret lab on it; it was not a livestreaming device, and he wouldn't get a connection in the underground lab if it were. The evidence was destroyed after Gus killed Lalo. Eladio already knew Gus hated him because he ordered Max's death, and he's not naive enough to believe Gus forgave him.

That's right and Gus knew this. When he was saying it, he figured he would either win or die and if the latter, he wanted Eladio to really know how he felt. It is hard to keep track of technology -- I think I was assuming it was being livestreamed or at least uploaded, but isn't this all happening in the early stages of the Internet? In one episode at least (season 6) Saul is asked sarcastically if he has the Internet where he lives.

Canonically Gus and Lalo's showdown occurs in 2004, the same year as facebook's founding and before youtube, the iphone, and instagram, so while the technology did exist, it wasn't accessible off the shelf, and certainly not on a pocket video camera. Even ignoring that, if it were a livestream or a video call with Eladio, we would likely see or hear Eladio responding in real-time.
